# What's the equivalent of this Firestore code in Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following a tutorial but the guy is using Firebase Firestore and I already started a project with Firebase Realtime database, is there anyway I could change this code from Firestore to Firebase Realtime database?

```
firebaseDatabase.collection("Users").document(blogUserId).get().addOnCompleteListener
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code:

```
firebaseDatabase.collection("Users").document(blogUserId).get().addOnCompleteListener
```

Can be used in Firebase Realtime database like this:

```
firebaseDatabase.child("Users").child(blogUserId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

Comment: sorry for the late response i was a bit busy i tried it and yes it worked thank you so much :D